# Encrypting and using the .env file

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

In **Laravel v9.32** - they released a new feature where you could encrypt and decrypt the `.env` file to hide its content. See documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#encrypting-environment-files

It goes like this:

```
php artisan env:encrypt
```

It will create the file:

```
.env.encrypted
```

While also providing you with its decryption key to later on decrypt when needed.

So far so good! But no where in the documentation does it say how to use it, if you simply rename the file to `.env` you will get a server error, same thing if you just delete your `.env` file leaving the encrypted file.

The only place I can see that supports this is Laravel Vapor, but what about native laravel, how to use the new encrypted file?

Comment: i think this meant to be used with vapor ... and to be uploaded to your repo just so you can share it securely with your fellow project team members ... but not to be used as laravel self can't read encrypted file , you still need to use good old .env. ,   please read here https://www.amitmerchant.com/encrypting-and-decrypting-environment-files-in-laravel-9x/ under last paragraph "in closing"

Answer (score 0):

In order to use this feature you will need to run the `php artisan env:decrypt` command on the encrypted version of the file (using the same key you used to encrypt it in the first place.) This will output the unencrypted version of the file as a new `.env` file which your application would then be able to use as normal. (See the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#decryption) for full command usage details).

The intention of this feature, is that you can include the encrypted version of the file in your source code, or to transport it in a less secure manner, and then decrypt it for use on the server running the application (e.g. in your local environment, or on the production server).

For example, you may deploy your source code, including the encrypted version of your .env file, to your production server and then run the decrypt command as part of your post-deployment script on that server.